Is there a Ramda way to merge those two data arrays?
I need to merge two data arrays of the same shape.
My working code is this:
import * as R from 'ramda'

const expected = [
    [
        {
            "zeroData": false,
            "responseCount": [
                0,
                0,
                1,
                9
            ],
            "responsePercent": [
                0,
                0,
                0.1,
                0.9
            ],
            "index": 9.666666666666666,
            "stdDev": 0.9999999999999999,
            "expectedStdDev": 1.651740425387243
        }
    ]
]

const t1 = [
    [
        {
            "zeroData": false,
            "responseCount": [
                0,
                0,
                1,
                9
            ],
            "responsePercent": [
                0,
                0,
                0.1,
                0.9
            ],
            "index": 9.666666666666666,
            "stdDev": 0.9999999999999999
        }
    ]
]

const t2 = [
    [
        {
            "expectedStdDev": 1.651740425387243
        }
    ]
]

test('merge', () => {
    const merged = t1.map((arr1, idx1) => {
        return arr1.map((obj, idx2) => ({...obj, ...t2[idx1][idx2]}))
    })

    expect(merged).toStrictEqual(expected)
})

Is there a simple and elegant Ramda-way to do it? And especially a generic solution that would allow to specify the depth at which the merging should occur.
Tried various combinations of the R functions with no luck

According to the lib's official documentation, you can use mergeAll.
You will first need to flatten the arrays using concat then you can use the mergeAll
This is how you can achieve it:
import * as R from 'ramda'

const expected = [
    [
        {
            "zeroData": false,
            "responseCount": [
                0,
                0,
                1,
                9
            ],
            "responsePercent": [
                0,
                0,
                0.1,
                0.9
            ],
            "index": 9.666666666666666,
            "stdDev": 0.9999999999999999,
            "expectedStdDev": 1.651740425387243
        }
    ]
]

const t1 = [
    [
        {
            "zeroData": false,
            "responseCount": [
                0,
                0,
                1,
                9
            ],
            "responsePercent": [
                0,
                0,
                0.1,
                0.9
            ],
            "index": 9.666666666666666,
            "stdDev": 0.9999999999999999
        }
    ]
]

const t2 = [
    [
        {
            "expectedStdDev": 1.651740425387243
        }
    ]
]

test('merge', () => {
    const merged = R.mergeAll([].concat(...t1, ...t2));

    expect(merged).toStrictEqual(expected)
})

You can read this to learn more: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeAll
Edit
import * as R from 'ramda'

const expected = [
    [
        {
            "zeroData": false,
            "responseCount": [
                0,
                0,
                1,
                9
            ],
            "responsePercent": [
                0,
                0,
                0.1,
                0.9
            ],
            "index": 9.666666666666666,
            "stdDev": 0.9999999999999999,
            "expectedStdDev": 1.651740425387243
        }
    ]
]

const t1 = [
    [
        {
            "zeroData": false,
            "responseCount": [
                0,
                0,
                1,
                9
            ],
            "responsePercent": [
                0,
                0,
                0.1,
                0.9
            ],
            "index": 9.666666666666666,
            "stdDev": 0.9999999999999999
        }
    ]
]

const t2 = [
    [
        {
            "expectedStdDev": 1.651740425387243
        }
    ]
]

test('merge', () => {
    const merged = R.zipWith(R.merge, t1[0], t2[0]);

    expect([merged]).toStrictEqual(expected)
})

In this code, R.zipWith is used to merge objects at corresponding positions in the nested arrays t1 and t2.

Thank you for your answer, I'm aware that flattening helps, but the thing is I want to keep the data structure and the nesting of arrays.  Is there a way to do this?

You can use zipWith, I am going to edit my answer

R.merge is not a function, do you mean something like this: t1.map((entry, idx) => R.zipWith(R.mergeDeepLeft, entry, t2[idx]))
